# Android studio screen capture button is greyed out

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, screenshot

I created an android API level 30 emulator, and ran one of my apps from Android Studio. I'm quite sure this app doesn't have anti-screenshot features, and yet, I couldn't capture a screen shot as the "camera" icon near the logcat was greyed out. Any idea why, or how I could enable the screen shot functionality?
[image: The camera icon is in the bottom left in this image from my android studio]

The camera icon is at the bottom left in the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your given screen shot there is in red color text which shows "No Device". I thing you have start your emulator but please make sure emulator is online. if its still not work then restart your ADB and then try again

Comment: Actually, the red color text was showing "No debuggable process", but your answer helped me check that my logcat was for the wrong device (a phone that was actually connected to the machine, rather than the emulator I wanted). Switched in left-most dropdown to the emulator, and the camera button is ok now, thanks!